How do I get the fingerprint reader to work in Ubuntu 24 for ASUS expertbook P2 for Host: ASUS ExpertBook P2451FB_P2451FB 1.0
Following are the neo fetch details:
           .-/+oossssoo+/-.               kaal@kaal-ASUS-ExpertBook-P2451FB-P2451FB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ----------------------------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: ASUS ExpertBook P2451FB_P2451FB 1.0 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 6.8.0-31-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 1 hour, 59 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1990 (dpkg), 36 (brew), 38 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.2.21 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 46.0 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-prussiangreen-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru-prussiangreen [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: terminator 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-10510U (8) @ 4.900GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX110 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: Intel CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 5352MiB / 31932MiB 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
                                                                   
                                                                   
lscpi details:

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake-U v1 4c Host Bridge/DRAM Controller (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SATA AHCI Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02a8
00:1e.2 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 02aa
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP LPC Premium Controller/eSPI Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX110] (rev a2)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc 2300 NVMe SSD [Santana]


Need to know how can I find elan fingerprint drivers for my system

I am not able to use fingerprind enroll command option:
kaal@kaal-ASUS-ExpertBook-P2451FB-P2451FB:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ fprintd-enroll
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling right-index-finger finger.
Enroll result: enroll-unknown-error


Finally I found this trick for my fingerprint reader: Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c6e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint My system runs Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic with kernel 6.5.0-10-generic And it W O R K S ! ! ! ! ! ! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm1ig_VFxSs

I am not able to use fingerprind enroll command option:
kaal@kaal-ASUS-ExpertBook-P2451FB-P2451FB:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ fprintd-enroll
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling right-index-finger finger.
Enroll result: enroll-unknown-error
